# Using the object name i in a for loop as a character

Tags: r

I would like to call on a list of objects in a for loop.  Within that for loop I would like to use the name of my list object "i" within another list "n" as a character for a label on one of my graphs.

So, i would like i to be a chracters

I have tried

```
for(i in n){as.character(bquote(.(i))}
```

but it returns "i", and i need it to return i
So, if my object i is named cat, i want "cat", not "i".

And,

```
 for(i in n){quote(i)}
```

But, it converts everything within my list into a character.

Alright, here is an example

```
cat<-c(1,2,3,4)
dog<-c(5,6,7,8)
walrus<-list(cat=cat,dog=dog)

duck<-c(5,5,5,5,5)
goose<-c(6,6,6)
narwhal<-list(duck=duck, goose=goose)

polarbear<-list(walrus=walrus, narwhal=narwhal)

for(i in polarbear){print(as.character(i))}
```

I want "walrus" and "narwhal" as my output, but only one at a time.

Comment: Simple `plot(..., main = i)` doesn't work?

Comment: No, it returns every single variable in my list as the name.

Comment: So please share a reproducible example, as it should work as it. What is `n` object for example?

Comment: loop over the names, `for(i in names(n)) {... i ... n[[i]] ...}`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: But there is no "cat" and "dog" in `walrus`.

Comment: ^ check it out now.  This is exatly what i am dealing with.  I am trying to track the evolution of walrus's

Comment: only duck and goose ? Or cat, dog, duck and goose? because polarbear has walrus and narwhal both

Comment: `names(polarbear)` still gives you that

Comment: names(polarbear) give me c("walrus", "narwhal")  I need "walrus" and then "narwhal"

Comment: `for(i in names(polarbear)){print(i)}` as @baptiste suggested

Comment: I wish, but i can't figure out how to include a loop within my loop.  I am plotting in my loop with something like walrus and narwhal, so i need to name my graphs, walrus and narwhal.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't obvious what you are trying to do, but your data will probably be easier to work with as a data frame.  Convert it using the `listless` package (not yet on CRAN).

Get `listless`:

```
library(devtools)
install_bitbucket("graumannlabtools/listless")
```

Convert to data frame:

```
library(listless)
(polarbear_data <- list_to_data.frame(polarbear))
##     names1 names2 values
## 1   walrus    cat      1
## 2   walrus    cat      2
## 3   walrus    cat      3
## 4   walrus    cat      4
## 5   walrus    dog      5
## 6   walrus    dog      6
## 7   walrus    dog      7
## 8   walrus    dog      8
## 9  narwhal   duck      5
## 10 narwhal   duck      5
## 11 narwhal   duck      5
## 12 narwhal   duck      5
## 13 narwhal   duck      5
## 14 narwhal  goose      6
## 15 narwhal  goose      6
## 16 narwhal  goose      6
```

`polarbear_data` is in a form that will easily work with other tools, like `dplyr` or `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(polarbear_data, aes(interaction(names1, names2), values)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image: polar bear boxplot]